# Regarding threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I am facing one problem regarding threading scenario.

I have three threads in my process. One is subsystem1 thread , second is subsystem2 thread  and third one is store manager thread.

Both subsystem1 and subsystem2 thread invoke storemanager thread for making communication with database.

Can anybody help me how to call storemanager thread method or how to pass command to invoke store manager thread method from my sybsystem threads and to get the response back from store manager thread.

Need guidance in this. i am using c++ in linux.

Comment: Is you question basically how to call a thread (storeManager) from another thread (subSystem)?

Comment: Yes...i need to call a method in storemanager thread from other threads. Say there is a method called "Write" in storemanager thread. other threads will call this write and pass arguments and get the return response. I need this type of behaviour.

Comment: Add the tag c or c++, you will get more answers.

Comment: @noMAD: Don't add tags just to get more answers. Tags are for summarizing the fields in the question, not for attracting attention.

Comment: Maybe [message queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "invoking" a thread from another thread. Your three threads are running at the same time and independently of each other.

Your store manager thread acts as a worker thread that services requests from the other two threads.

When one of the subsystem threads needs to issue a database operation it sends some form of message to the store manager thread that contains the information about the function that needs to be executed. One way to implement this communication is with a thread-safe queue. The subsystem thread in this case will add a job request to a job queue.

The store manager thread monitors the job queue and executes job requests from the queue as they are added by the other threads. Jobs that are complete are removed from the queue.

Note that the subsystem threads will not block while the store manager thread performs a requested task. Instead, you have to develop a communication mechanism between the threads by which the subsystem threads can find out when a job is complete and obtain information about the result if necessary.

I recommend that you read on thread-safe data structures and synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *storeManager(void *arg)
{
    printf("\nI am storeManager function\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *subSystem(void *arg)
{
   pthread_t newThread;
   printf("I am subSystem function\n");
   pthread_create(&newThread, NULL, storeManager, NULL);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads;
   printf("In main: creating subSystem thread\n");
   pthread_create(&threads, NULL, subSystem, NULL);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Here you are creating new thread. But let say two threads are already running , then how will call method of one thread from another thread to assign a task?

Comment: You can only create a thread and assign a method to it. When a thread is already running, you cannot simply call it like an ordinary method. The POSIX API has a `pthread_create` function to create a thread and assign it a method. If you want to assign a new method or the same one to another thread, you need to create a new thread. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: But I still don't understand your point here. If you have a separate method `write()` then you can call it inside or outside of any number of threads (just make sure they don't enter a race condition). If you have a method `void *write(void *arg)` then the only way that I know of calling it is `pthread_create()`

Comment: He might be looking for a signal or condition mechanism? Depending on if the other thread tends to block when awaiting a subsystem command or what...

Comment: @Platinum :  in signal or condition mechanism , you cannot pass argument to destination thread. you can only signal to proceed or not to proceed.

Comment: True. In that case you want a message queue.